# Refactoring code, to make concurrent api requests? using queue and threading

Tags: python, python-requests, python-multithreading

there are 451 stores where i need to get their subsquent store details through api requests, which has caused the program to siginificantly slow down which is due to it waiting to get the data. I know i can use queues and threading to get past this but i've been stuck in the mud trying to figure this out and reaching out for some help

```
def retrieve_stores_data(api_endpoint: str, headers = None):
    
    number_of_stores_endpoint = 'https://aqj7u5id95.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/prod/number_stores' #api endpoint where i need to tack on the number of the store
    
    stores_data = [] # used to store the returned data from the api
    url_data = [] # using it to store the urls for each store

    if(headers == None):
        with open('API_Keys.yaml', 'r') as stream:
            headers = yaml.safe_load(stream)
    
    number_of_stores = DataExtractor.list_number_of_stores(number_of_stores_endpoint, headers) #another method which returns the number of stores in int (450 stores)
   
    for store_id in range(0, number_of_stores):
        url = api_endpoint + f'{store_id}' #adds the store_id onto the incompleted endpoint
        url_data.append(url)
        print(url_data)
    
    for url in url_data:    
        response = requests.get(url = url, headers = headers) #calls the api for each url
        stores_data.append(response.json()) # appends the data on to the store details
        
       
    
    store_data = pd.DataFrame(stores_data) # add to a dataframe for future cleaning
    
    return store_data
```

I know instead of having url_date i can use a queue and put every url onto the queue but i'm not exactly sure how to recode it to include threading also i apologise i know there are many questions similar to this that has been answered which i had a look at but i still weren't able to wrap my head around it, please have patience with me

Comment: you don't even need to create your own queues and buffers, look at `ThreadPoolProcessor` where you can do something like `futures = [executor.submit(apiCallToRetereiveStoreData, url_data[start:end]) for _ in range(numThreads)]` and then iterate over the result using `for future in futures: future.result()`

Comment: @OM222O I do apologise i've been busy but i've implemented this without the range but it did take the time for all the requests to go through initially from 700seconds down to 230 seconds which is a substantial difference thank you for the initial comment